# Is there a maximum amount of cells you can set when using Excel Services REST API with SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office365apis

I'm trying to use the Excel REST API with SharePoint Online to set some cell values and to retrieve some calculated fields.

It seems this goes well up until passing 10 cell values. When passing more I receive this error from the API:

> 503 Service Unavailable

The amount of characters in the URI is less than the approximant supported 2000 characters.

Any limitations on the maximum amount of fields you can set is not described in the documentation of the [Unsupported Features in Excel Services REST API (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394477.aspx).

Example (Backslashes at the end of each line acutally not part of the URI):

```
https://business-my.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx \
    /personal/john/documents/some.xlsx/model/Ranges('Input_Output!S2|S13')?$format=atom& \
    Ranges('Input_Output!C3')=val1& \
    Ranges('Input_Output!C4')=val2& \
    Ranges('Input_Output!C5')=val3& \
    Ranges('Input_Output!C8')=val4& \
    Ranges('Input_Output!G2')=val5& \
    Ranges('Input_Output!G3')=val6& \
    Ranges('Input_Output!G4')=val7& \
    Ranges('Input_Output!G5')=val8& \
    Ranges('Input_Output!G6')=val9& \
    Ranges('Input_Output!G10')=val10
```

I did noticed the following in the response header:

```
X-XLSMsgId:RequestLimitsExceeded
```

What exactly does it mean? Would it be possible to set mulltiple cells in a range instead of separate query parameters to overcome any limits?